# Entityframework vs NHibernate in Mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4

Hey Friends i need one suggestion regarding to EF and Nhibernate. Currently i am developing an application in MVC4 using  MSSql 2008 R2 and entity framework. But now i have to use Mysql 5.5 as database. As i am completely new to mysql i don't whether EF is supportive to it or not.

I search in net and get some information about it. But i want to know whether it is better to use ****NHibernate**** or **EF** in mysql 5.5. And Whether EF in mysql is as similar to MSSql

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal rule of thumb is that if you are developing application using SQL Server ONLY than go for Entity Framework as they are rapidly improving and bringing out great features.

Whereas if you have to work with other database as well, Oracle and MySql etc, then go for NHibernate, their community is larger and proven.